# printing a receipt in C#

Tags: c#, graphics

Hi I'm trying to print a bill for a certain transaction and i've done it but the subtotal is printing over the total line... your help is appreciated. 
My Code below

```
    offset = offset + 20;
        graphics.DrawString("Total : ".PadRight(40) + total.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY);

        graphics.DrawString("SubTotal : ".PadRight(40) + subtotal.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY);
```

Comment: `startX, startY` seems you are having same values for both total and subtotals. what are the values you are having there?

Answer (score 1):

The line `graphics.DrawString("SubTotal : ".PadRight(40) + subtotal.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY);` is set (via `startY`) to write at the same y co-ordinate as the previous line.

Best to increment the startY by the font height. Something like:

```
offset = offset + 20;
graphics.DrawString("Total : ".PadRight(40) + total.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY);

startY += font.Height;
graphics.DrawString("SubTotal : ".PadRight(40) + subtotal.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY);
```

This increments the `startY` by the `font.Height` amount which by [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.height(v=vs.110).aspx) is

> Gets the line spacing of this font.

Remarks:

> The line spacing is the vertical distance between the base lines of two consecutive lines of text. Thus, the line spacing includes the blank space between lines along with the height of the character itself.